# Removing elements from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to remove certain elements from an `ArrayList<String>`

```
for(int i=0; i<myList.size(); i++)
{
    if(myList.get(i).contains("foo"))
    {
        myList.remove(i);
    }
}
```

This however leaves "empty spaces" in my list. I would like the list to leave out the empty elements and after iterating through it shrink to neccessary size.

Is there a smart way to do this without having to switch to a `LinkedList`?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> This however leaves "empty spaces" in my list.

No, it doesn't. It removes entries from the list completely. Other elements are moved appropriately. What it *does* do with the way you've written is skip the check for the next entry... because that will have "shuffled down" to be element `i`, but you'll next look at element `i + 1`.

One simple way to avoid this is to work backwards instead:

```
for (int i = myList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (myList.get(i).contains("foo")) {
        myList.remove(i);
    }
}
```

Or use an iterator as noted in other answers, of course. Both will work - the above code may be slightly more efficient if you're removing multiple entries, however, as there'll be less to shift by the time you get to the start. It's unlikely that that will be significant.

It's unfortunate that in order to use the iterator solution you have to use the iterator *explicitly* - you can't remove from a collection while using an [enhanced for loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html).

Comment: Once again, awesome answer.. Cheers!

Comment: does the array behind the `ArrayList` also shrink while items are removing?

Comment: @erencan: Not as far as I'm aware, but the trailing elements are populated with `null` to avoid GC issues. You can call `trimToSize` afterwards if necessary, but that's rarely useful IME.

Comment: @JonSkeet Empty elements in the sense what exactly, I'm confused. Why that gives an empty space ?  I did'nt found any evidence  by testing it here  https://ideone.com/Kti3s2 Am I missing something ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: I didn't refer to "empty elements" - the OP referred to "empty spaces" but as I stated in my answer, that's misdiagnosis. What exactly are you referring to? If you mean the trailing null elements in the array, they aren't visible in terms of the normal list operations - they're spare capacity, essentially.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yup.Gotcha. That makes sense. Thanks for the info's. Confused with OP's  description.

Comment: Erm, isn't this algorithm quadratic in the size of the list? This approach is probably not a good idea if the list is long ...

Comment: @meriton This algorithm is BigO(n), not quadratic. Any `ArrayList` item can be accessed BigO(1) by its index.

Comment: @erencan: Sure, but remove takes O(n). For instance, if every second item needs to be removed, there will be n/2 removals, each of which copies n/4 elements on average, causing a total number of copies of n^2 / 8.

Answer (score 7):

Use an `Iterator` and call [`Iterator.remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) instead.

```
Iterator it = myList.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    if (it.next().contains("foo")) { 
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

This way you will also avoid trouble for reducing the size of the list while relying on it as an exit condition to your loop, and accessing it using indexes that might be varying.

Of course iterating through the list backwards will also work.

Answer (score 3):

The smart way you're looking for is the `Iterator` interface. For example:

```
Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
   String nextItem = it.next();
   if (nextItem.contains("foo")) {
      it.remove();
   }
}
```

Comment: There's no risk of ConcurrentModificationException in the existing code... although it has another problem, as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Influenced by `Scala` and functional programming, I would recommend you to just copy your values to new list for immutability.

```
List<String> filtered = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String s : myList) {
   if (!s.contains("foo")) {
       filtered.add(s);
   }
}
```

I would also recommend 2 libs to try out: `Guava` and `lambdaj`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Isn't this a waste of resources considering larger scales? The first list doesn't get collected immediately, right? I just don't want to use up more resources that I really need, even though this is a clear and simple approach.

Comment: This solution is good if reference to previous list is used by some other part of program or your will save complete data set for future. In any case this approach is safer than modifying existing list. Memory consumption is not a problem, since you still will reference to already existing in memory objects.

Answer (score 2):

ArrayList maintains an array behind the scene. I want to deep into source code of `java.util.ArrayList` and `java.util.LinkedList`.

First of all ArrayList maintains an array behind the scenes. Once you create an ArrayList instance it creates an array whose size is 10 and it grows while the elements inserted. It is size grow to 3(size)/2 +1

Here is the source code.

Default size of arrat list. Look at [constructer code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.%3Cinit%3E%28%29).

```
public ArrayList() {
         this(10);
    }
```

its size grows to 3(size)/2 + 1. here is the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.ensureCapacity%28int%29). [ArrayList#ensureCapacity](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.ensureCapacity%28int%29http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.ensureCapacity%28int%29) method is called insite [ArrayList#add](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.add%28java.lang.Object%29)

```
public void ensureCapacity(int minCapacity) {
         modCount++;
         int oldCapacity = elementData.length;
         if (minCapacity > oldCapacity) {
             Object oldData[] = elementData;
             int newCapacity = (oldCapacity * 3)/2 + 1;
             if (newCapacity < minCapacity)
                 newCapacity = minCapacity;
             // minCapacity is usually close to size, so this is a win:
             elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, newCapacity);
        }
     }
```

When you remove any item from ArrayList. It is removed from the list and other list items is shifted down to the removed items location. Take special attention, reference to this object is set to null and object become eligible to GC, but there is still a reference allocated for ArrayList. **The array size behind the ArrayList is same**.

Here is the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.remove%28int%29)

```
public E remove(int index) {
         rangeCheck(index);

        modCount++;
         E oldValue = elementData(index);

         int numMoved = size - index - 1;
         if (numMoved > 0)
             System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                              numMoved);
         elementData[--size] = null; // Let gc do its work

         return oldValue;
     }
```

As Jon Skeet answered, when an item is removed next item to removed item will be in the removed items location.

However, allocated memory space is the same after removal. java.util.LinkedList is stands for this issue. All items inside LinkedList is dynamicly allocated and deallocated (It is GC's work, of course)

java.util.LinkedList maintains a [doubly linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list) behind the scenes. Each add and remove operations changes the memory space used by LinkedList. The item is removed and reference to item from its previous and next items is updated.

[Here is the source code :](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.entry%28int%29)

```
private Entry<E> entry(int index) {
        if (index < 0 || index >= size)
           throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: "+index+
                                                ", Size: "+size);
        Entry<E> e = header;
        if (index < (size >> 1)) {
           for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
                e = e.next;
       } else {
            for (int i = size; i > index; i--)
                e = e.previous;
        }
       return e;
   }
```

I assume that GC collects items as soon as it is removed, i know it is not certain. But removed memory location is a candidate to GC. Please be careful about the reference to the object and the object itself.

Both ArrayList and LinkedList removes items while ArrayList still stores a reference for object types and memory space for primitive types, Linked list also removes references and memory space. At least, references and memory also will be eligible to GC.

Answer (score 1):

After you remove list will automatically shrink.

Suppose you remove element at index 3, that element will be removed, list will shrink and the element that was at index 4 will have index 3 after remove.

You should do this:

```
for(int i=0; i<myList.size(); i++)
{
    if(myList.get(i).contains("foo"))
    {
        myList.remove(i);
        // as element is removed, next element will have decremented index
        i--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No it won't leaves "empty spaces" in your list, but you will miss removing all required elements from your list.

Lets try to explain with below example.
I am having a ArrayList with 4 elements. (a,b,c,d).

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (((String) list.get(i)).contains("c")) {
                list.remove(i);
            }
            if (((String) list.get(i)).contains("b")) {
                list.remove(i);
            }
        }

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(list.get(i)+" ");
    }
```

Result: a c d

When traversing the list in forward direction, I tried removing elements (c,b) but still element c is present in my list.

To avoid this we can traverse in backward direction like below.

```
for (int i = list.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (((String) list.get(i)).contains("a")) {
                list.remove(i);
            }
            if (((String) list.get(i)).contains("c")) {
                list.remove(i);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print(list.get(i) + " ");
        }
```

Result: b d